# Bootstrap modal popup close on button (type=submit) post back asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

bootstrap modal popup on post back event of button (type=submit) it's close automatically.asp.net c# web form. (type=submit)

**Solutions that don't work**:

1. I could not get it to work with an Update Panel.
2. Can't reopen like javascript thorough again modal popup show. Because I am opening modal up from different page.

   ```js
    function OpenModal() {
       var strUrl = "page.aspx";
       $('.modal-body').load(strUrl, '', function () {
           $('#myModal').modal();
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: "asp.net can't use two form tags" ... what?! are you using webforms here . You should be a bit more clear about the main technology you are using

Comment: yes i am using web forms.

Comment: I am not too sure how you how you can do this in webforms but you need to pass the model from the one page , the original page, to the new page , the new page with the model , that should then hold all the values that you want to post back to the server. Basically the last submit need all the model details and then it can have a redirect back to the other page ... fyi ... use asp mvc its all a lot easier to do

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerdi :) but issue is modal close on postback of button click. and if i use update panel then it's not working because they both conflicting.

Comment: I think because you are calling it with .load. Maybe webforms then still registers 2 forms because technically there has not been a full refresh. What if you do a full post to a new page with the modal being called on the page load. I realize this messes a bit with the ux but , webforms is not the most friendly in terms of ux.

Comment: issue found page corrupt as per u say "The modal popup didn't get to browser after post back." But how to maintain it. still i didn't found it. it works like charm with modalpopupextender ajax but with bootstrap it's not."